# Can't import paramiko in Python 3/Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies, apt, ubuntu-16.04

I installed the `paramiko` lib with Ubuntu's APT repositories (`sudo apt-get install python3-paramiko`), and I can't import it :

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'paramiko'
```

But when I install it with `pip3 install paramiko`, the `import paramiko` line works !

I could just stick with the `pip` version, but I want to distribute this program, and it would be very convenient to give all the dependencies as APT packages.

Why can Python import the `pip` version, but not the APT one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the apt package is installed to a dir not recognized by python3, that is, not in one of `sys.path`. compare the installed dir of python3-paramiko and the output of `python3 -c  'import sys;print(sys.path)'`.

Also, it's good practice for your python package to depend on packages installed by pip. Since you could distribute your package via `setuptools` and configure your dependency therein. Which make your  program cross platform.